# Math mode producing errors

Tags: tables, math-mode

I had a strange issue where text following \cup would be in italics (maybe math mode showing?). Whenever I use `\textsuperscript{\ell}` to have a superscripted `\ell` symbol - it will take anything following (even outside the curly bracket) and superscript it as well.

To counter it I have encased ALL special symbols like `\ell` and `\cup` in math mode.
It solved the problem but...

Now my table has taken revenge on me and in the following code block seven of the first 8 lines within the tabular block produces the error `"Missing $ inserted."`

Why? ...and can it be helped?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([int x;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\ 
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([int[n] A;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\  
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([\{int fst; int snd\} R; ]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset    \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{1} D\textsubscript{2}) & = & \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{1})  $\cup$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(D\textsubscript{2})) | $\ell \in$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{final}(D\textsubscript{1})\}  \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([$\ell$ := a;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([R := (a\textsubscript{1}, a\textsubscript{2}); ]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([read k;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}([write $\ell$;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & \emptyset \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1} S\textsubscript{2}) & = & \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1}) $\cup$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{2})) | $\ell \in$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{final}(S\textsubscript{1})\}  \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(if [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$} \{S\textsubscript{0}\}) & = & \{($\ell$l, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{0}))\} $\cup$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{0}) \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(if [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}\{S\textsubscript{1}\}else\{S\textsubscript{2}\}) & = & \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1}) $\cup$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{1})),$\ell$, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{2}))\}  \\
    \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(while [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$} \{S\textsubscript{0}\})  & = & \{($\ell$, \textcolor{forestgreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{0}))\} $\cup$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{0}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$', $\ell$) | $\ell$' $\in$ \textcolor{forestgreen}{final}(S\textsubscript{0})\} \\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Function flow in MicroC.}
\label{table:MicroCFunctionFlow}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was that the marking `\emptyset` is a math-mode symbol.

`$\emptyset$`  is what it should be.

Try that.  Worked for me:

I also tweaked your color name.  Your MWE with some small fixes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{RGB}{34,139,34}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([int x;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([int[n] A;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([\{int fst; int snd\} R; ]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$    \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{1} D\textsubscript{2}) & = & \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{1})  $\cup$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(D\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(D\textsubscript{2})) | $\ell \in$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{final}(D\textsubscript{1})\}  \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([$\ell$ := a;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([R := (a\textsubscript{1}, a\textsubscript{2}); ]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([read k;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}([write $\ell$;]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}) & = & $\emptyset$ \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1} S\textsubscript{2}) & = & \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1}) $\cup$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{2})) | $\ell \in$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{final}(S\textsubscript{1})\}  \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(if [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$} \{S\textsubscript{0}\}) & = & \{($\ell$l, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{0}))\} $\cup$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{0}) \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(if [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$}\{S\textsubscript{1}\}else\{S\textsubscript{2}\}) & = & \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{1}) $\cup$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{2}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{1})),$\ell$, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{2}))\}  \\
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(while [b]\textsuperscript{$\ell$} \{S\textsubscript{0}\})  & = & \{($\ell$, \textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}(S\textsubscript{0}))\} $\cup$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}(S\textsubscript{0}) $\cup$ \{($\ell$', $\ell$) | $\ell$' $\in$ \textcolor{ForestGreen}{final}(S\textsubscript{0})\} \\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Function flow in MicroC.}
\label{table:MicroCFunctionFlow}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I should of course have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: Or `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`, and `ForestGreen` (and every other CSS/HTML color) is already defined.

Answer (score 3):

You have `\emptyset` in text mode.

However, your input should be treated as all math, in my opinion.

Here are three realizations of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cflow}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{flow}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cfinal}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{final}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cinit}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{init}}
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vr}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ @{} c @{{}={}} c @{} }
  \cflow([\fn{int} x;]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\ 
  \cflow([\fn{int}[n] A;]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\  
  \cflow([\{\fn{int} \vr{fst}; \fn{int} \vr{snd}\} R; ]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\
  \cflow(D_{1} D_{2}) & 
    \cflow(D_{1}) \cup \cflow(D_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(D_{2}))\mid\ell \in \cfinal(D_{1})\} \\
  \cflow([\ell := a;]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\
  \cflow([R := (a_{1}, a_{2}); ]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\
  \cflow([\fn{read} k;]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\
  \cflow([\fn{write} \ell;]^{\ell}) & \emptyset \\
  \cflow(S_{1} S_{2}) &
    \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{2})) \mid \ell \in \cfinal(S_{1})\} \\
  \cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\}) & \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \\
  \cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell}\{S_{1}\} \fn{else} \{S_{2}\}) &
    \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{1})),\ell, \cinit(S_{2}))\}  \\
  \cflow(\fn{while} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\}) &
    \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \cup \{(\ell', \ell) \mid \ell' \in \cfinal(S_{0})\} \\
\end{array}
\]

\caption{Function flow in MicroC.}
\label{table:MicroCFunctionFlow}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp!]

\[
\begin{aligned}
& \cflow([\fn{int} x;]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\ 
& \cflow([\fn{int}[n] A;]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\  
& \cflow([\{\fn{int} \vr{fst}; \fn{int} \vr{snd}\} R; ]^{\ell}) = \emptyset    \\
& \cflow(D_{1} D_{2}) =  \cflow(D_{1})  \cup \cflow(D_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(D_{2}))\mid\ell \in \cfinal(D_{1})\}  \\
& \cflow([\ell := a;]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\
& \cflow([R := (a_{1}, a_{2}); ]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\
& \cflow([\fn{read} k;]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\
& \cflow([\fn{write} \ell;]^{\ell}) = \emptyset \\
& \cflow(S_{1} S_{2}) = \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{2})) \mid \ell \in \cfinal(S_{1})\}  \\
& \cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\}) = \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \\
& \cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell}\{S_{1}\} \fn{else} \{S_{2}\}) = \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{1})),\ell, \cinit(S_{2}))\}  \\
& \cflow(\fn{while} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\})  = \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \cup \{(\ell', \ell) \mid \ell' \in \cfinal(S_{0})\} \\
\end{aligned}
\]

\caption{Function flow in MicroC.}
\label{table:MicroCFunctionFlow-2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp!]

\[
\begin{aligned}
\cflow([\fn{int} x;]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\ 
\cflow([\fn{int}[n] A;]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\  
\cflow([\{\fn{int} \vr{fst}; \fn{int} \vr{snd}\} R; ]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset    \\
\cflow(D_{1} D_{2}) &=  \cflow(D_{1})  \cup \cflow(D_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(D_{2}))\mid\ell \in \cfinal(D_{1})\}  \\
\cflow([\ell := a;]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\
\cflow([R := (a_{1}, a_{2}); ]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\
\cflow([\fn{read} k;]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\
\cflow([\fn{write} \ell;]^{\ell}) &= \emptyset \\
\cflow(S_{1} S_{2}) &= \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{2})) \mid \ell \in \cfinal(S_{1})\}  \\
\cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\}) &= \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \\
\cflow(\fn{if} [b]^{\ell}\{S_{1}\} \fn{else} \{S_{2}\}) &= \cflow(S_{1}) \cup \cflow(S_{2}) \cup \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{1})),\ell, \cinit(S_{2}))\}  \\
\cflow(\fn{while} [b]^{\ell} \{S_{0}\})  &= \{(\ell, \cinit(S_{0}))\} \cup \cflow(S_{0}) \cup \{(\ell', \ell) \mid \ell' \in \cfinal(S_{0})\} \\
\end{aligned}
\]

\caption{Function flow in MicroC.}
\label{table:MicroCFunctionFlow-3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

#### Center alignment

[image]

#### Left alignment

[image]

#### Right-left alignment

[image]

Comment: Very nice the choice of the color ForestGreen given also for the user @jdw